# Set default radio button on webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a standard contact page created using *webform*, which has a set of radio buttons.

Is it possible to change the pre-selected radio option based on the referring page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add ?selectValue=yourvalue to the links pointing to your webform.

Then, create a template node--webform.tpl.php, check if i'm in the correct webform with the $node object and if $_GET['selectValue'] is set. Then use jQuery to select my radio button.

It might not by the perfect solution, but it's clearly a way out!

Comment: This solution needs jQuery enabled, there is better approaches on this topic like tokens or just do a custom form_alter

Answer (score 1):

With Webform you can pre-populate form default values via the url with tokens:

**Setting Default Values from the URL (7.x-3 and earlier)**

The `%get[key]` supported by Webform allows form values to be populated from the URL.

**Setting Default Values from the URL (7.x-4)**

To set the default values of a component to use either:

**Query Format**: For urls formatted like http://example.com/node/120?key=bar use `[current-page:query:key]` to return key value.,

**Args Format**: For urls formatted like http://example.com/node/120/key use `[current-page:url:args:2]` to return key.

Taken verbatim from [webform docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/296453)

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 using Webforms module you can do the following:

admin/structure/webform/manage/donation/source

Add:
'#default_value': 'Yes'

To the radio button defined in the YML.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding new field in webform, select "Select option" in the type of field. After that you will get a field configuration page. In field configuration page you will see 3rd option as default value. You can put default value for that field.

Comment: When I set the default value there, it is the same no matter what page you come from. I want the default option to change. Eg. if clicking the webform link from the sales page, then the sales enquiry radio option is pre-selected by default; if clicking webform from about us page, then general enquiry option is pre-selected.