# Set default selected radio button on webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a standard contact page created using webform, which has a set of radio buttons. How can I make one of the radio buttons selected by default?

This quesion is similar, but it relies on the refering link, which I would rather not. 
[Set default radio button on webform](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19425/set-default-radio-button-on-webform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an option to set a default value when you go to edit that field in the webform. You have to set it to the "key" of the value you want selected by default. Your options should be listed as key|value under the field options.
[image]